# ReactJS Date Input Component - Issues with Year Input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm working on a ReactJS project where I have a date input component. I'm facing two issues with this component that I need help with:

**Issue 1: Year Input Length**
The first issue is that the year input allows six digits. I want to limit it to just four digits (e.g., 'YYYY'). Currently, users can input a date like '01/04/202222' in the year section, which isn't ideal. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```js
<input
    data-form-user="birth_date"
    value={userInfo?.birth_date && moment(userInfo?.birth_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
    // ...
    type="date"
    // ...
/>
```

**Issue 2: Modifying Year in Date Format**
The second issue is related to modifying the year. When I input a date like '01/04/2008' and try to change the year to a date in the 1900s, it doesn't allow me to modify the first two digits of the year (e.g., '01/04/19XX' won't work). Only the last two digits of the year (2000s) can be updated. I want to be able to change the full year. Here's the code for the onChange event:

```js
onChange={(event) => {
    const selectedDate = event.target.value;
    const parsedDate = new Date(selectedDate);
    setStartDate(parsedDate);
    const formattedDate = moment(selectedDate).format('MM/DD/YY');
    setUserInfo((prev) => {
        return {
            ...prev,
            "birth_date": formattedDate
        };
    });
}}
```

If you're looking for the complete input code:

````js
```<input
    data-form-user="birth_date"
    value={userInfo?.birth_date && moment(userInfo?.birth_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
    required
    type="date"
    id="birth_date"
    name="birth_date"
    class="form-control font-weight-bold rounded-0 border-[#000000]"
    placeholder="Date of Birth"
    onChange={(event) => {
        // Get the selected date as a string (format: YYYY-MM-DD)
        const selectedDate = event.target.value;
        // Example: Thu Sep 28 2023 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)
        const parsedDate = new Date(selectedDate);
        setStartDate(parsedDate);
        // Format the date as 'MM/DD/YY'
        const formattedDate = moment(selectedDate).format('MM/DD/YY')
        setUserInfo(prev => {
            return {
                ...prev,
                "birth_date": formattedDate
            }
        });
    }}
    autoComplete="off"
/>
````

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to address these issues. Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Issue #1:**
Since this is birth date it should be max only of today's year so what i did is get the date today and set it as max.

```js
const today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
<input
//other attributes..
max={today} 
/>
```

**Issue #2:**
The issue is the attribute for value should be `defaultValue=` and not `value=`.

```js
<input
//other attributes..
defaultValue={userInfo?.birth_date && moment(userInfo?.birth_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
/>
```